# Is there a way to inspect the graph of a sparse matrix with PETSc?

Tags: matrix, petsc, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

I am currently trying to code the [CA-CG method](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~mhoemmen/pubs/thesis.pdf) within the PETSc framework. A mandatory step in this process is the implementation of the "matrix powers kernel" algorithm for a generic sparse matrix.

This requires the computation of the [index set](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/IS/IS.html) obtained exploring the graph associated with the sparse matrix for s-steps, starting from the index set of the local rows "owned" by each process.

**Is there a clean way to retrieve this kind of information using the PETSc API?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MatIncreaseOverlap()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatIncreaseOverlap.html) just like `PCASM` (additive Schwarz preconditioner) to get the overlapping region, then [`MatGetSubMatrices()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatGetSubMatrices.html) (also like `PCASM`) to pull out the overlapping part of the matrix.

For further technical discussion of implementation, we encourage you to subscribe to `petsc-dev@mcs.anl.gov` or just email `petsc-maint@mcs.anl.gov`.

Comment: Many thanks! That worked out exactly as expected.